# Changing css folder from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html + css + javascript application.
I want to be able to enable theming.

All my css are replicated in two folders: /theme1/... and /theme2/...

So my html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme1/file1.css"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme1/file2.css"/> 
         .... 
         ....
    </head>
    <body>  
    .....
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to change using javascript the home folder of the css (theme1 to theme2).

Any ideas?

Comment: Plenty. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you will need to solve the problem:

- Get the relevant tags. In this case, any `link` tag with `rel="stylesheet"` will probably do, but you can even go so far as to specify "starting with `theme1`" if you want. This can all be done with `document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet][href^=theme1]")`
- Loop through them. A simple `for` loop will do nicely.
- `getAttribute("href")` gets the string you need.
- `replace()` will allow you to replace the part of the string you want.
- `setAttribute("href",newattr)` will put the attribute back into the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link id="foo" rel="stylesheet" href="theme1/file1.css"/>
```

When you want to change the theme:

```
document.getElementById('foo').href = 'theme1/file2.css';
```

Comment: That changes one file. What about the others?

Comment: _"I want to be able to change using javascript the home folder of the css (theme1 to theme2)."_ I didn't understand you comment at all.

Comment: Well for starters there are two `link` tags in the question that need changing, and the `....` suggests there may be more. Second, you are changing `file1` to `file2`, not `theme1` to `theme2`.

Comment: Let me try again: You are not answering the question in any way, shape or form.